# Query parameters not working with MS Access ADP project

Tags: ms-access, subform, adp

I want to create two linked subforms on a form. For this I need to set query parameter into the record source of the second subform like this:

```
select col1, col2
from my_table
where col3=[Forms]![MyForm]![subform1]![MyField]
```

This works with .accdb file, but not with Access Project (.adp file), connected to SQL Server. There I get "Invalid syntax near '!'". Tried many other ways, but could not make it to work.

Comment: Oliv, it is nice to acknowledge responses to your questions, if the answer is not suitable a comment will do. You might like to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette

Comment: We switched back to ACCDB because of this, so no problem anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ADP version, your query is run by SQL Server's db engine, which knows nothing about `[Forms]![MyForm]![subform1]![MyField]`.  In the ACCDB version, the query is run by Access' db engine, which does know about `[Forms]![MyForm]![subform1]![MyField]`

See whether you can put the second subform into a subform control on subform1.  If that arrangement can work for you, use subform1's [MyField] as the link master and col3 as the link child.  (Those are set with the link master/child property of the subform control.)  The effect will be to filter the second subform's records --- display only those records where col3 matches the MyField value of the current record in subform1.

Comment: That would work, but the subform1 is in Datasheet view, so it does not display subforms.